# Copy a picture in a scrolling flash window

Tags: flash, window, scrolling

I'm trying to copy pictures of a product (camera: Sony NEX-5N)

Found here ► http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16830179468&Tpk=NEX5NK

When clicking on the picture, a window pops up where I can select different pictures of that camera. If I click on the picture in the window on the left hand side, it zoomes in. Problem is that I am not able to copy the full size picture because the window only shows a part of it.

Comment: Where are you clicking the pictures? Are you using the camera’s software? What do you mean by “copy”? Are you talking about copying the files or copying the screen with the `PrtScr` key. What about just plugging the card into the computer and accessing the files directly or configuring the camera to appear as a drive when connected to the computer?

Comment: Sorry, I think I totaly failed in expressing myself properly.
There is this website with some pictures of this camera. I was trying to save these pictures to my hard drive but the right click doesn't offer the "save as" option. I'm now wondering if there's any other way to save the pictures.

Comment: A screenshot is worth a thousand words. `;-)`

Comment: Alright, here is a screenshot of what I mean.

http://www.abload.de/img/screenshotu0ko3.png

I'm trying to save this picture on my hard drive, but clicking the right mouse button only offeres me useless options.

Comment: And here is a second screenshot of a picture, 

http://www.abload.de/img/screenshot251k1o.png

which is only showing a part of the whole camera and because I would like to save the whole picture, using the "print screen" trick doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, you don’t even have the camera. Okay, then this is probably off-toppic here, but what about clicking the `[-]` or `[Reset]` buttons to adjust the zoom?

Comment: Oh yeah, I can make the picture smaller, so that it fits the window. But I was hoping to copy the full size picture in higher resolution.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment and deleted my response and wrote up an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use your browser’s dev-tools (it depends on what browser you are using) to find the URL to the actual file. The location of the URL will vary from site to site.

Another way would be to extract it from the browser cache:

- Clear your browser’s cache
- Reload the page
- View the images
- Open the folder where your browser stores its cache (again, depends on the browser)
- Copy the files somewhere and then either view them if they have filenames/extensions or use a tool like [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to identify the file-types and then view them
- Copy the ones you want

Comment: Alright this is a little strange.

1. I have just now installed the FireFox addon called "CacheViewer Continued 0.8"
2. I then cleared my cache
3. pressed Ctrl + Shift + C to bring up the cache viewer, it was empty
4. Then I viewed one image and zoomed in
5. Then I refreshed the cache viewer (bottom left hand side)
Double clicking on one of the bigger file sizes really brought up the full size image, but in poor picture quality.
I'm puzzled.

Comment: How so?​​​​​​​​

Comment: Hi, here is a picture showing the differences:

http://www.abload.de/img/2xqy3b.png

On the left hand side you can see the picture zoomed to level 2 (out of 3). On the right hand side is the picture taken from the cache of the browser. Looking closely you can see a significant difference in picture quality. This is very tricky, isn't it?

Comment: NewEgg doesn’t use JPGs, it uses Flash, even for the [individual photos](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3e0.png). They do however have static images (for that camera they’re `images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/30-179-468-Z01` to `http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/30-179-468-Z09`). What browser are you using, did the file in the cache have a filename?